ZYNQ XC7Z010-3CLG400E - Can I use SPI MIO to EMIO?
This will be my first attempt to design PCB based on Xilinx Zynq device. The specific part number is XC7Z010-3CLG400E. My main objective is to learn how to design high speed peripherals including DDR3, Ethernet, and USB 3.0. I am also planning to use this as mainboard to test some sensors in the future. I wanted to make sure that I could use SPI peripherals in some PS units that is compatible to PL pinout so that I could use to connect external sensors. According to the datasheet, it has 2 x SPI pinout and 2 x I2C. PS pinouts are currently used up all due to other high speed signals. If it's possible to route those SPI or I2C MIOS to EMIO, is there anything that I need to be aware of? any limitations? I currently have most PL banks available.
Thank you

Proper layout and routing are necessary for high-speed signals. Also, pay attention to trace lengths, impedance matching, and crosstalk, especially if the peripherals will operate at higher frequencies.
Use ground planes and controlled impedance traces for SPI signals to maintain signal integrity.

what is a ps unit and pl, along with mio and emio

It works just fine. I've done that myself when I needed to run the SPI interface at a different logic voltage from the one I was using on the MIO banks.
